# How to create a new column based on row value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to iterate through the rows in pandas and create a new column based on the value. I have my data set here:

```
  Political Entity  Recipient ID           Recipient Recipient last name  \
0       Candidates          4350       Whelan, Susan              Whelan   
1       Candidates          4350       Whelan, Susan              Whelan   
2       Candidates          4350       Whelan, Susan              Whelan   
3       Candidates          4350       Whelan, Susan              Whelan   
4       Candidates         15453  Mastroianni, Steve         Mastroianni   

  Recipient first name Recipient middle initial Political Party of Recipient  \
0                Susan                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   
1                Susan                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   
2                Susan                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   
3                Susan                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   
4                Steve                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   

  Electoral District        Electoral event Fiscal/Election date  \
0              Essex  38th general election           2004-06-28   
1              Essex  38th general election           2004-06-28   
2              Essex  38th general election           2004-06-28   
3              Essex  38th general election           2004-06-28   
4  Windsor--Tecumseh  40th general election           2008-10-14   

        ...       Monetary amount Non-Monetary amount  \
0       ...                 800.0                 0.0   
1       ...                1280.0                 0.0   
2       ...                 250.0                 0.0   
3       ...                1000.0                 0.0   
4       ...                 800.0                 0.0
```

I want to create a new column where it takes the political party and the year date and add the Monetary value. For example:

```
+------------------------------+----------------------------+--+--+--+
| 2004 Liberal Party of Canada | 2004 Green Party of Canada |  |  |  |
+------------------------------+----------------------------+--+--+--+
| 8000                         | 0                          |  |  |  |
+------------------------------+----------------------------+--+--+--+
|                              |                            |  |  |  |
+------------------------------+----------------------------+--+--+--+
|                              |                            |  |  |  |
+------------------------------+----------------------------+--+--+--+
```

I have created a couple of functions to help get started:

```
def year_political_column(row):
    return row['Fiscal/Election date'][:4] + ' ' + row['Political Party of Recipient']


def monetary(row):
    return row['Monetary amount']
```

Whenever I look up my solution it seems like you have to already have the column set. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Sample output should be:

```
  Political Entity  Recipient ID           Recipient Recipient last name  \
0       Candidates          4350       Whelan, Susan              Whelan   
1       Candidates          4350       Whelan, Susan              Whelan   
2       Candidates          4350       Whelan, Susan              Whelan   
3       Candidates          4350       Whelan, Susan              Whelan   
4       Candidates         15453  Mastroianni, Steve         Mastroianni   

  Recipient first name Recipient middle initial Political Party of Recipient  \
0                Susan                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   
1                Susan                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   
2                Susan                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   
3                Susan                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   
4                Steve                      NaN      Liberal Party of Canada   

  Electoral District        Electoral event Fiscal/Election date  \
0              Essex  38th general election           2004-06-28   
1              Essex  38th general election           2004-06-28   
2              Essex  38th general election           2004-06-28   
3              Essex  38th general election           2004-06-28   
4  Windsor--Tecumseh  40th general election           2008-10-14   

        ...       Monetary amount Non-Monetary amount  \
0       ...                 800.0                 0.0   
1       ...                1280.0                 0.0   
2       ...                 250.0                 0.0   
3       ...                1000.0                 0.0   
4       ...                 800.0                 0.0   

  Contribution given through Ontario first name Ontario last name  \
0                        NaN                J M            
1                        NaN                  J             
2                        NaN                  B            
3                        NaN                  H            
4                        NaN                  H            

   Ontario Address Ontario city Ontario Province Ontario Postal Code  \
0                

  Ontario Phone #  
0      
1      
2      
3      
4
```

With all the political data I am looking for attached on the right.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create your year-party column and then do something like `crosstab` or `pivot`

Comment: How can I dynamically create these columns? @user3483203

Comment: I think you can do a groupby: ````df.groupby('Political Party of Recipient')['Monetary amount'].sum()````, and then use transpose: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Comment: How am I able to do this by year as well? As in have all years and political parties from 2004 up to 2018? @xyzjayne

Comment: See my answer -- I created a 'year_political' column like yours (except it doesn't have to be done with a function, you can just add columns), and then I did a groupby based on this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished via a variety of ways:

- `pivot`
- `pivot_table`
- `groupby`

However, most of them will need some brushing to output the format you need. Only number 2 will work if you are not looking for an aggregate function and would like the entries.

```
def column_name(row):
    return '{} {}'.format(row['Fiscal/Election date'].year, row['initial Political Party of Recipient'])

df['Fiscal/Election date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fiscal/Election date'])

df['Column Name'] = df.apply(column_name, axis=1)
```

1) `pivot_table`

```
In [4]: df[['Column Name', 'Monetary amount']].pivot_table(columns='Column Name'
   ...: , 
   ...:                                                    values='Monetary amou
   ...: nt', 
   ...:                                                    aggfunc='sum')
   ...:                                                    
Out[4]: 
Column Name      2004 Liberal Party of Canada  2008 Liberal Party of Canada
Monetary amount                          3330                           800
```

2) `pivot`

```
In [5]: (df[['Column Name', 'Monetary amount']]
   ...: .pivot(columns='Column Name', values='Monetary amount'))
Out[5]: 
Column Name  2004 Liberal Party of Canada  2008 Liberal Party of Canada
0                                   800.0                           NaN
1                                  1280.0                           NaN
2                                   250.0                           NaN
3                                  1000.0                           NaN
4                                     NaN                         800.0
```

3) `groupby`

```
In [6]: pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Column Name')['Monetary amount'].sum()).transpo
   ...: se()
Out[6]: 
Column Name      2004 Liberal Party of Canada  2008 Liberal Party of Canada
Monetary amount                          3330                           800
```

Comment: Nice summary. ````pd.to_datetime```` could be time-consuming for larger datasets though. Using a 4-char slice is probably good enough for extracting year.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, it's more of a habit to deal with dates as `datetime` objects rather than strings, can't help not do it.

Comment: Wow... absolutely amazing detailed answers from both you and @xyzjayne. I ended up using the `pivot` method. That being said, how do you keep the remaining column that I had previously?

Comment: What do you mean by remaining column?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them, especially when there are multiple recipients in a single election season. Do you want a list of names and IDs or a single recipient?

Comment: After using your pivot example, I got a keyerror on my dataset when trying to get all values in the row. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you update the question with a sample of the output you need?

Comment: Updated. Some data has been removed as it is confidential. @iDrwish

Comment: I fixed this issue by just doing a merge on the index of both dataframes. This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a column using election year and party name, then do a groupby and transpose:

```
df['year_political'] = df['Fiscal/Election date'].astype(str).str.slice(0,4) + ' '+ df['Political Party of Recipient']
df.groupby('year_political')['Monetary amount'].sum().reset_index().transpose()
```